# segfault only when NOT using debugger

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have a multithreaded C program, which consistently generates a segmentation fault at a specific point in the program. When I run it with gdb, no fault is shown. Can you think of any reason why the fault might occur only when not using the debugger? It's pretty annoying not being able to use it to find the problem!

Comment: This kind of bug is called ["Heisenbug"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#Heisenbug) and can have many causes.

Comment: Does the error happen to be related to window management and/or User32.dll?

Comment: I had an issue like this, my program only crashed with GDB.  The issue was an unintialized class member variable was still getting the value 0 when I ran my program, but when I ran it in GDB it had some huge value that segfaulted when I used it as an array index.

Comment: Not windows related - I'm using Linux 2.6.32-24-generic #43-Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried arranging a core dump? Run `ulimit -c unlimited` before you start the program outside the debugger, then `gdb myprogram core` after it dumps core. gdb will then be able to post mortem your segfault.

Comment: What is happening at that specific point in the program?  Are you attempting to deference a pointer?  Call another function?  What?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Classic [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug). From Wikipedia:

> Time can also be a factor in heisenbugs. Executing a program under control of a debugger can change the execution timing of the program as compared to normal execution. Time-sensitive bugs such as race conditions may not reproduce when the program is slowed down by single-stepping source lines in the debugger. This is particularly true when the behavior involves interaction with an entity not under the control of a debugger, such as when debugging network packet processing between two machines and only one is under debugger control.

The debugger may be changing timing, and hiding a race condition.

On Linux, GDB also disables address space randomization, and your crash may be specific to address space layout. Try `(gdb) set disable-randomization off`.

Finally, `ulimit -c unlimited` and post-mortem debugging (already suggested by Robie) may work.

Comment: 'set disable-randomization off' solved a similar issue for me!

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps when using `gdb` memory is mapped in a location which your over/under flow doesn't trample on memory that causes a crash.  Or it could be a race condition that is no longer getting tripped.  Although it sounds unintuitive, you should be *happy* your program was nice enough to crash on you.

Some suggestions

1. Try a static code analyzer such as the free
   [**cppcheck**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/files/cppcheck/1.46.1/)
2. Try a malloc() debugger like
   [**libefence**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libefence)
3. Try running it through [**valgrind**](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 5):

By debugging it you are changing the environment that it is running in.  It sounds like you are dealing with some sort of race condition, and by debugging it things are scheduled slightly differently so you don't encounter the issue.  That, or things are being stored in a slightly different way so it doesn't occur.  Are you able to put some debugging output in the code to assist in figuring out the problem?  That may have less of an impact and allow you to find your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have totally had this problem before!  It was a race condition, and when I was stepping though the code with a debugger the thread i was in was slow enough to not trigger the race condition.   Pretty awful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `gcc`, try using the `-Wall` option to get all warnings. If you use an IDE like Eclipse, it would do that automatically.